# Deadlock vicitm detected with two UPDLOCKS

Tags: sql-server

How is this possible? For my understanding if i already have an UPDLOCK in the first process. The second process needs to wait or hang in the select, during the time the first process are not commiting the transaction.

Deadlockgraph:

[image: Deadlock-Graph]

```
<deadlock-list>
<deadlock victim="process1f37b18c108">
<process-list>
<process id="process1f37b18c108" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057594088980480 (22cb2de3bf06)" waittime="1446" ownerId="230178654" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-04-13T14:40:02.193" XDES="0x1f57387c428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="2092" status="suspended" spid="80" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-04-13T14:40:02.193" lastbatchcompleted="2022-04-13T14:40:02.193" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.193" clientapp="SITLOG-WMC" hostname="LAGW6ML001" hostpid="0" loginname="bml1gdb" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="230178654" currentdb="8" currentdbname="BML1GDB" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="128" stmtend="356" sqlhandle="0x02000000012fda2a8b70601ac4d20eae5633914dd83d1eea0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown </frame>
<frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
(@P0 datetime2,@P1 int,@P2 bigint,@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4 bigint)UPDATE SYS_SCHED_SEQUENCE SET mod_ts = @P0, seq_next = @P1, VERSION = @P2 WHERE ((IDENT = @P3) AND (VERSION = @P4)) </inputbuf>
</process>
<process id="process1f5665664e8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057594088980480 (334bd54e4e37)" waittime="1446" ownerId="230178657" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-04-13T14:40:02.193" XDES="0x1f51d020428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="4332" status="suspended" spid="88" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2022-04-13T14:40:02.193" lastbatchcompleted="2022-04-13T14:40:02.193" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.193" clientapp="SITLOG-WMC-SL-BML1G-WMC-SYS-SCHEDULER" hostname="LAGW6ML001" hostpid="0" loginname="bml1gdb" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="230178657" currentdb="8" currentdbname="BML1GDB" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="290" sqlhandle="0x020000009b29c10ffdd03721b9f269c4eca16d8a5f55d5820000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown </frame>
<frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))SELECT IDENT, seq_end, gen_ts, mod_ts, seq_next, seq_start, VERSION FROM SYS_SCHED_SEQUENCE WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE (IDENT = @P0) </inputbuf>
</process>
</process-list>
<resource-list>
<keylock hobtid="72057594088980480" dbid="8" objectname="BML1GDB.dbo.SYS_SCHED_SEQUENCE" indexname="PK_SYS_SCHEDSEQ" id="lock1f44ce78600" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594088980480">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process1f5665664e8" mode="U"/>
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process1f37b18c108" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
</waiter-list>
</keylock>
<keylock hobtid="72057594088980480" dbid="8" objectname="BML1GDB.dbo.SYS_SCHED_SEQUENCE" indexname="PK_SYS_SCHEDSEQ" id="lock1f11847bb00" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594088980480">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process1f37b18c108" mode="U"/>
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process1f5665664e8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
</waiter-list>
</keylock>
</resource-list>
</deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Edit:
We already found the answer in the Excution Plan as in the comments got suggestions. The Executionplan was unexpectedly using an Index Seek wich causing the whole Key to be locked and not a single Row.
This happend because of different Types in the Preparedstatement "nvarch" and the column definition type "varchar".

Comment: Posting the code too would help. Are you taking out locks on all the resources, or just one? If just one, then you're not preventing the "deadly embrace" of a deadlock.

Comment: Please share the execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. I expect the issue here is that you are reading rows in different orders (because they're using different indexes)

Answer (score 2):

> How is this possible?

SQL Server uses mostly row-level locking, and so both queries start running and taking U locks on the keys they read (one because it's an UPDATE statement, and the other because it's a SELECT with UPDLOCK hint).

Soon, each process owns U locks on many different keys.  Then one session needs a U lock on a key locked by the other and blocks.  Then the unblocked session needs a U lock on a key owned by the blocked session, which is a deadlock.

Comment: That by itself won't cause a deadlock. it will only deadlock if the two queries read in different orders. So if they are forced to read from the same index in the same order then a deadlock will never happen

Comment: Yes.  If they read the same index in the same order, then one will simply get blocked until the other is finished.  Here the two queries are probably using different indexes and different access plans.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that the Queryparam were implicitly converted into NVARCHAR. So that the UPDLOCK locks not only one Index.

Now we changed the Collation from `SQL_Latin1_CP1_CI_AS` to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

Possible is also to set the property "sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false" in URL.